# Modifying Messagebox?

Tags: vb6

Heloo there? Is there any way to change the color [back and forecolor] of a **Messagebox**? Iam using VB6.0... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do this. There is, however, a typical workaround.

The most common method for creating custom "message boxes" in VB6 is to create a new form in your project that acts specifically as a message box. You `Show` it when you need it, and then `Hide` or `Unload` it when the user clicks "OK" or "Cancel" or whatever. You can size the form the same as (or differently from) a `MsgBox`, create the buttons you want, make the colors as you choose, etc. Whenever you would have a message box pop up to tell the user something, you will instead call this form and change the text/color/other variables to whatever you need them to be.

This may seem annoying at first, but once you've done it once, it's very easy to see how useful a tool this new form template can become. It's code you might find yourself frequently reusing between various applications.

If you need any help with forms or form events, this is a pretty good basic tutorial which should tell you most of what you need to make this work:
http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-forms-vb6-tutorial

Good luck!