# How To Create Messagebox Manually?

Tags: vb6

With VB6, I want to make a messagebox manually so that I could modify its format and style with my own... Can anyone give me a tutorial[website] for this?

Answer (score 0):

Any tutorial on building a VB6.0 form will do.  [Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=custom+messagebox+vb6) is your friend.

Try this one: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=445165

Comment: ...the admin had banned my IP address. I cant access the site

Comment: @aerohn - then pick one of the other hits in the Google search

Answer (score 0):

Create a form as you would normally, when you open it, you open it modally, this is the only difference.
You can make your own procedures to open it with given parameters if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

aerohn, I did kind of already answer this question in your previous question:

[Modifying Messagebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566152/modifying-messagebox)

Try some code for the new message box form, and if you run into problems with it then ask a question about those problems. It's pretty simple, though... just make a form, throw on a label, size and color it however you'd like, and create a button or two to close the form. From your recent previous questions it looks like you know how to make a decent looking form; I think you can do this pretty easily.

Good luck!